# Quaternion.LookRotation( ) does not work properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new in Unity and I try to rotate an arrow to point to a specific object (in my case the left triangle from the screenshots). I used the lookRotation() function but I do not know why it does not work properly. Here are some screenshots. Any suggestions?

```
public Transform target;

public Transform source;

public GameObject bigArrow;

void Start()
{

}

void Update()
{
    Vector3 direction = target.position - source.position;

    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);

    source.rotation = rotation;

    // ...
}
```

[image: What I get when I run the application]

[image: If I change the position of the triangle the arrow rotate but not in the correct direction]

[image: Initial arrow direction]

Comment: You need to set the arrows initial forward direction correctly in the editor, Tip: towards the Z axis is typically "forward".

Comment: Like in the last screenshot?

Comment: @holo1 Next time please include your code into your question as text, and not as an image. Having your code as an image makes your question slower to answer as people have to re-type your code to include it in their answer, it makes the question harder to find for people with a similar problem who are searching for it, and it makes your question less accessible to people who use a screen reader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Furthering my comment to answer a question to it.

You want to put the arrow GameObject inside of an empty GameObject so that you can orientate it within the world coordinates to point forward.

Like so

[image: Image of an arrow orientated towards the Z Axis]

You can then rotate the Arrow Holder with `Quaternion.LookRotation` using its forward direction as the look direction it points.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to wrap the arrow inside an empty gameobject, an alternative solution is to take into account which direction the arrow is pointing.

The arrow is pointing in the local direction of `Vector3.left`. You can tell because the tip of the arrow is pointing opposite from the local red axis arrow.

So, we can use [`Quaternion.FromToRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.FromToRotation.html) to create a rotation that will rotate the tip of the arrow (which is pointing in the `Vector3.left` direction) to the local `Vector3.forward`  direction.  Then we multiply the result of `LookRotation` by this modifying rotation to produce the rotation we are interested in:

```
void Update()
{
    Vector3 direction = target.position - source.position;

    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);

    rotation *= Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.left, Vector3.forward);

    source.rotation = rotation;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I prefer your answer but for a beginner I think my answer is easier to wrap your head round.